# IE7 BUTTON white outline

Tags: html, css, button, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Does anyone know why IE6 and IE7 add a white border between a `button` border and the background?

Here is my CSS and HTML:

```
#reportButton{
    background:#fefcda url(buttonback.png) repeat-x bottom left;
    border-top:2px solid #fffff8;
    border-right:2px solid #e3b40c;
    border-bottom:2px solid #e3b40c;
    border-left:2px solid #fffff8;
    color: #373535;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin:0 2%;
    width:45%;
}

<button id="reportButton">Report a Concern</button>
```

If you try this, you will see a funny white border between the borders and the background. This does not appear in any other browser, not even IE8.

Anyone have a simple fix or suggestion as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: I just noticed that when I click on the button, the marching ants come up and the white border disappears. It seems as though when the button is `:active` they disappear, although this doesn't help me much in terms of solving the problem, maybe it will for someone else.

Also, sorry I cannot provide a screen; I have no place to upload it now via this internet connection.

EDIT2: It actually appears that the border is not white but the `background-color` of the button. It appears IE is leaving a 1px gap between the button border and the button background image.

Comment: Are you using a reset.css?  Guessing that would probably fix this but unable to test right now.

Comment: @kekekela: I'll try right now. EDIT: That didn't work either...

Comment: Ah, sorry bud. =/   I'll take a look at it when I get home tonight if you haven't figured it out by then.

Comment: I tried the code you have above (in appropriate places -- IE, the CSS in a style tag, the button in the body tag), on a black background, in IE6, 7 and 8 (using [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage), admittedly). Could not replicate the described behavior, no unusual border around the button in any of them. What `DOCTYPE` are you using, if any?

Comment: @John Rudy: I am using IE8 in Compatibility Mode and MultipleIEs for IE6. The 1px white border shows up in those. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: @tau: I tried both IETester and IE8's compatibility mode, and didn't get the described behavior in either. I tried both with no `DOCTYPE`, and with the default XHTML 1.0 transitional that you get when creating a new HTML page in Visual Studio, and neither of those replicated in any browser I threw at it. It may be MultipleIEs, or it may be your specific background, or it may be the specific `DOCTYPE` ... Lots of maybes, sadly, no definite answer just yet.

Comment: @John Rudy: I just tried different doctypes (I'm using strict) and that didn't change anything. I just edited my above post to say that it's not a white border, but rather a gap between the button's borders and the button background image. It did not matter which background image I used; the gap shows up with any background image.

Comment: I see what you're talking about now; I missed the fact that there was a background-image on the button itself; the weird border is *inside* the button's rectangle. I can't explain that one either, but I *was* finally able to replicate it when I loaded up my own background image in the button. Based on your second edit, can you select a background-color that's "closer" to your background-image main color? Or ... what happens if you remove the background-color altogether?

Comment: @John Rudy: Unfortunately the background image is a gradient, so any color I choose will make it look odd. Removing the background image entirely simple produces a white gap.

I'm starting to think there is no true solution to this bug, short of adding unnecessary elements to the page.

Comment: @tau: I was afraid that might be the case. Sorry, bud. :(

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem...neat trick that seems to work at least for IE:
The "white" outline is actually the background color of your image.   So set this to be the same as your border color.   If you don't mind a slightly-thick-ish border, stop there.   If the border is now too thick, set your border color to the background color of the page.

e.g. to display a black "border" use this css for your button:
background: url(./button_bg.gif) no-repeat;
background-color:#000000;
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;

Comment: Didn't originally ask the question but this solution worked for me. I've been wondering for ages what that white border is for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that that border is not coming from the image itself (background of the image), set the accurate `width` and `height`, also try setting the `padding` to `0` like @SLaks said.

Comment: I just tried all of those (and various combinations of those) and none of them got rid of it.